# Shipout line like Shipout page

Tags: packages, line-breaking, line-numbering, output-routine

In [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) package guide, I found:

> Attaching line numbers after TeX has broken the paragraph into lines
>   is already quite a difficult job for TeX. Why? Because TeX does not
>   normally give you any control after line breaking. `lineno.sty` does it
>   by pretending that the current page ends after each and every line.
>   This keeps TeX quite busy, but works.

I know the package [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) which offers `\EveryShipout`, `\AtNextShipout` and `\AtBeginDocument`.

Is there a package that provides `\EveryShipoutLine`, `\AtNextShipoutLine` and `\AtBeginParagrapheLine`?

Otherwise, I have to improve my knowledge of TeX and dissect the `lineno` package.

Addition, an example of usage :
[image: Exemple]

Comment: What is it that you would like to do with them?  `LuaTeX` offers "callback filters" that provide functionality such as you describe, see for example [This](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100isambert.pdf), but whatever work you want done would need to be coded in lua(/tex).

Comment: My idea is to use a larger font size for the first line and decreased the size of a few lines to complete the normal size. Or a line of color and the second in another color. I read the article and I come back.

Comment: If you turn your comment in response, I'll vote for it. I have work to do before we can understand all the subtleties of Tex, Latex and LuaTEX! but I'm working on it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LuaTeX provides `callbacks` from which the lines of a paragraph (and paragraphs themselves among other things) can be intercepted and manipulated.  I'm just fiddling around with this myself, here are some resources that I found useful (in order):

1. [LuaTeX: What it takes to make a paragraph-Isambert](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100isambert.pdf)
2. [The `chickenize` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/chickenize)
3. [Three things you can do with LuaTeX that would be extremely painful otherwise-Isambert](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99isambert.pdf)

The `chickenize` package is more of an instructional tool than anything else, it describes how to use callbacks and implements all sorts of strange things with them.  On this site, searching for `post_linebreak_filter` etc. will give you some further examples.